# How to pass selector as data argument to .on() with event.stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have event.stopPropagation() to work on a few selectors, but now I need to pass those selectors as an argument to .on(), since those elements are being replaced after an ajax request.

[image]

This is what I have and works (but breaks when the ajax replaces the selector elements):

```
$('.addSetMenu input, .addSetMenu select, .addSetMenu').on('click', function(event) {
    return event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I'm trying to pass the selectors as arguments to .on() as data, since the ajax request replaces all of those elements, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.addSetMenu input, .addSetMenu select, .addSetMenu', function(event) {
     return event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: What do you see happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If the `on()` is bound to the `document`, hasn't the `event` *already* propagated..? Unless I'm missing something this *can't* work (as you want it to).

Comment: Use $('.addSetMenu input, .addSetMenu select, .addSetMenu').live('click', function(){..});

Comment: @Fari: [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and in earlier versions `delegate()` is recommended instead. Check the API link.

Comment: @Fari that is the exact same thing as doing `$(document).on(...)`, except using deprecated syntax.

Comment: Should I be using .delegate() in this instance? I thought that .on() supercedes .live() and .delegate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine `stopPropagation()` with delegated event handling in your second code example.  That's because delegated event handling uses event propagation in order to work.  So, by the time your event bubbles up to the document object (where it will be processed by your event handler), it has already propagated so you can't stop the propagation that has already happened.

The real solution here is probably in understanding what you're really trying to stop.  If you truly need to stop event propagation, then you will have to rebind the first type of event handlers each time you replace the content with ajax (being careful not to get any duplicate event handlers).  But, if we knew what you were really trying to prevent with the `stopPropagation()` call, we might be able to offer a simpler solution.

Judging by your pasteBin example, I see three possibilities:

1. Change your code to handle the clicks and stopPropagation to a common parent that's before your close handler.  This is probably the better solution, but I'd have to know more about your HTML structure and what you are dynamically loading with ajax to know if this could work and exactly what code would work.
2. In your close handler (the code in your pasteBin example), examine the actual click target and don't call `resetMenu()` if the target is one of the items in your selector.  You can use the `.is()` method on the event target to determine that.
3. Each time you reload the content via ajax, re-install your event handlers using the static version of `.on()` (your first code example).

Comment: I was wondering what might be the workable solution to maintaining event.stopPropagation for working on those elements, even when they're replaced by new ones?

Comment: @SCS - what are you trying to prevent with the `stopPropagation()` call?

Comment: I have a function bound to <html> that will close a menu. All the selectors that I'm using event.stopPropagation on, I'm trying to keep from bubbling up to the html element and firing the function that closes that menu: http://pastebin.com/Y6Lp6bgS

Comment: I added some ideas to my answer for how to fix your issue.

Comment: This is my structure for the menu, which is nested within a table cell, and the entire table's html is replaced via the ajax call: http://pastebin.com/3JjxmP92 There's a way to reinstall event handlers?

Comment: @SCS - I don't read whatever template language your HTML is in.  Did you see the options I added to my answer?  You can reinstall event handlers by just calling the `$('.addSetMenu input, .addSetMenu select, .addSetMenu').on(...)` again after the ajax content is reinserted as long as all prior objects in that selector have been removed so you won't get any duplicate event handlers.

Comment: I tried out #2 and it worked wonderfully. Marking as solution. Thanks!